# Go xml.Marshal returns invalid characters

Tags: xml, encoding, go

I use the code below generate a XML encoding of string str:

```
str := string([]byte{0x01})
marshalBytes, _ := xml.Marshal(str)
fmt.Println(string(marshalBytes)) // output: <string>�</string>; � is [239 191 189] in bytes.
```

Obviously, � is not equivalent of 0x01.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you on Windows, in a DOS windows? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/12053168/6309)

Comment: I am on osx. And the answer is given by Charlie Tumahai.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bytes [239 191 189] are the UTF-8 encoding of the [Unicode Replacement Character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character).

The XML marshaler replaces the byte 0x1 with the Unicode Replacement Character because 
the byte 0x01 is not a [legal character in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets).

It is not possible to prevent the XML marshaler from using the replacement.

Comment: If I want to transfer byte 0x01 in a xml file, How can I achieve that?